# Can any LME be used for Mr. Beer kits or is it suggested to only use theirs?

Tags: beer, first-time-brewer, recipe, lme

I'm looking for alternative LME providers to use with my 6 gallon Mr. Beer kit. Coopers LME selection is decent, but I was wondering if anyone has used other brands of LME before with Mr. Beer. If so, how did it compare with the Coopers line? Are there any advantages/disadvantages to any brands?

Comment: It should be the same, maybe the taste is better on one vs the other....but here's a suggestion. weigh some of each type, mix with water and then get gravity readings on each. They should be almost the same. If not, you may need to adjust your recipe. Essentially, you need your final product the have a similar O.G. to end up with similar beer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LME (or DME) from any provider, they're all *basically* the same. There might be slight differences in sugar content, flavor, color, quality, &c., but LME is LME.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you can use any LME or DME. Check out multiple vendor's 5G Extract with or without steeping grains recipes. BrewDemon.com has their own 6G recipes along with Black Rock LME recipes. Advantages would be more variety of beer types instead of being limited to just whatever Mr. Beer or Coopers sells? 
Hope this helps to answer your question.